# Run through a few URLs, and import data from each

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to loop through a few URLs.  This is just a learning exercise for myself.  I thought I basically knew how to do this, but I have become stuck. I believe my code below is close, but it’s not incrementing for some reason scraping anything.

```
library(rvest)
URL <- "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=mens%27s+shoes+size+11&rt=nc"
WS <- read_html(URL)
URLs <- WS %>% html_nodes("ResultSetItems") %>% html_attr("href") %>% as.character()
```

Basically, I went to ebay, entered a simple search term, found a key node, named ‘ResultSetItems’, and tried to scrape the items from that.  Nothing happened.  Also, I’m trying to figure out how to increment through let’s say 5 URLs, and apply the same logic.  The URLs would look like this:

```
'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=mens%27s+shoes+size+11&_pgn=1&_skc=0&rt=nc'              
    
'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=mens%27s+shoes+size+11&_pgn=2&_skc=0&rt=nc'

'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=mens%27s+shoes+size+11&_pgn=3&_skc=0&rt=nc'

'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=mens%27s+shoes+size+11&_pgn=4&_skc=0&rt=nc'

'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=mens%27s+shoes+size+11&_pgn=5&_skc=0&rt=nc'
```

I think the code should look something like this:

```
for(i in 1:5) 
{
  
   site <- paste("https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=mens%27s+shoes+size+11&_pgn=",i,"&_skc=0&rt=nc", jump, sep="")
   dfList <- lapply(site, function(i) {
       WS <- read_html(i)
       URLs <- WS %>% html_nodes("ResultSetItems") %>% html_attr("href") %>% as.character()
   })
}
finaldf <- do.call(rbind, webpage)
```

I can’t seem to get this working.  I may be over-simplifying things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to. Given a set of urls (`read_url` in my case) you only need to apply using `map`function.

```
library(rvest)
read_url %>% 
  map(~read_html(.))%>% 
  map(html_nodes, css = "xxxx") %>% 
  map(html_nodes, xpath = "xxx") %>% 
  map(html_attr, name = "xxx") %>%
  unlist()
```

You will get a list of objects on which you can apply the same functions to get the data you want. Once you have done it you just have to put the list together in a data frame.

But watching http://www.ebay.com/robots.txt seems to be not allow to scrape in this domain of ebay. Maybe you should choose another example to try. ;)
HTH!

> **Edited**

Your example on ebay can not give results because it is prohibited. To be more clear, I will use the example of [this web page](http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html) that allows web scraping. **This is how I do it to avoid using functions of the apply family**. First, we **generate the list of pages** from which to obtain information.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

urls <- "http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-"

pag <- 1:5

read_urls <- paste0(urls, pag, ".html")

read_urls %>% 
  map(read_html) -> p
```

Once obtained the information **simply extract the information you want**, using `html_nodes` to access through the information contained (using css and xpath when necessary), finally accessing to `attr` in title case or simply with `html_text` in price example. Finally convert to tibble:

```
#Extract titles from the pages
p %>%  
  map(html_nodes, "article") %>% 
  map(html_nodes, xpath = "./h3/a") %>% 
  map(html_attr, "title") %>% 
  unlist() -> titles

#Extract price from the pages
p %>% 
  map(html_nodes, "article") %>% 
  map(html_nodes, ".price_color") %>% 
  map(html_text) %>% 
  unlist() -> prices

r <- tibble(titles, prices)
```

As result:

```
# A tibble: 100 x 2
                                 titles prices
                                  <chr>  <chr>
1                  A Light in the Attic £51.77
2                    Tipping the Velvet £53.74
3                            Soumission £50.10
4                         Sharp Objects £47.82
5 Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind £54.23
6                       The Requiem Red £22.65
```

Now it is possible to turn all this into a function.  But I leave in your hands.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean?  Your code doesn't actually do anything at all.  I know what you mean...I don't necessarily want to screen-scrape ebay links.  I just want to learn the concept, which I thought I knew, but as I see now, I don't really understand how this stuff works.  Thanks.

Comment: Answer edited to provide a more accurate example, hope that helps! An a happy web scraping :)

Comment: AWESOME!!  Thanks so much for sharing this!!